# Import Image on Matrixblock via GraphQL Mutation

Tags: craft3, matrix, image, graphql

I'm trying to create an Entry via a GraphQL mutation. The whole Entry consists of one Matrix(handle: `siteimportmatrix` ) with one Block(handle: `importblock` ) which has 4 fields one of the fields is an image(handle: `importbild`) which I want to upload with the mutation, prefered as Base64 encoded string.
I am able to fill all the other fields via the mutation but I fail at providing the image. Can somebody help me with this one? The documentation from Craft is somewhat elusive to me in this specific topic.

Here is my Mutationschema:

```
mutation MyMutation($title: String, $slug: String, $siteImportMatrix: [siteimportmatrix_MatrixBlockContainerInput], $sortOrder: [QueryArgument]) {
  save_sozialinfowien_genericimport_Entry(
    title: $title
    slug: $slug
    siteId: 56
    siteimportmatrix: {sortOrder: $sortOrder, blocks: $siteImportMatrix}
  ) {
    title
    slug
    dateCreated @formatDateTime(format: "Y-m-d")
    siteimportmatrix {
      __typename
      ... on MatrixBlockInterface {
        id
      }
      ... on siteimportmatrix_importblock_BlockType {
        importhtmlcode
        importgenerictext
        importnotizen
        importbild {
            filename
          fileData
        } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but this yields this error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"fileData\" on type \"AssetInterface\". Did you mean \"filename\"?",
      "extensions": {
        "category": "graphql"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 22,
          "column": 11
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```